# Java Quickstart Build Failed With non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I followed the steps in the Google Sheets api in Java, when I ran "gradle -q run" it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
    at Quickstart.authorize(Quickstart.java:69)
    at Quickstart.getSheetsService(Quickstart.java:92)
    at Quickstart.main(Quickstart.java:100)
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':run'.

  > Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

What do I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
    at Quickstart.authorize(Quickstart.java:69)
    at Quickstart.getSheetsService(Quickstart.java:92)
    at Quickstart.main(Quickstart.java:100)
```

.. means that some code have accessed variable that is actually null in code of class `Reader`.

Most likely you have passed null to `InputStreamReader` in your code of `Quickstart.authorize` at line `Quickstart.java:69`.

Checking for null variable could be done like this:

```
if(var == null) {
  var = new SomeClass();
} 
// do something with var
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, the issue was that file the code was looking for was named incorrectly.